# Android sax parser image and text and passing into the next activity

Tags: android, parsing, saxparser

I want to parse it through SAX Parser and the load the image through url and pass it to the next activity to show. But am failing to do so if any can help me out or give me some reusable code then it would be grateful. here is my xml file. Here is my parsed data class and adapter class.Now i want to parse the data like(date , cost , description , image) and put everything into string to their individual tag and when required i can pass it onto the next activity. Please help also i need to implement share on the image so i need url of the image from xml

**PARSEDDATA CLASS**

public class ParseData extends DefaultHandler 
{
    boolean title , cost , pubDate , link = false;

```
StringBuffer stringTitle , stringCost  , stringPubdate , stringLink = null;

ArrayList<String> arrtitle = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> arrcost = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> arrpubDate = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> arrlink = new ArrayList<String>();



//---------START ELEMENT----------//

@Override
public void startElement(String uri , String localName , String qName , Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
{
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {
        title = true;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("cost"))
    {
        cost = true;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
    {
        pubDate = true;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
    {
        link = true;
    }
}
//--------END ELEMENT----------//

@Override
public void endElement(String uri , String localName , String qName) throws SAXException 
{
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {
        title = false;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("cost"))
    {
        cost = false;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
    {
        pubDate = false;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
        link = false;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException 
{
    super.characters(ch, start, length);


    if(title)
    {
        stringTitle = new StringBuffer("");
    title_flag = true;
    }

    if(cost)
    {
        stringCost = new StringBuffer("");
        cost_flag = true;
    }

    if(pubDate)
    {
       stringPubdate = new StringBuffer("link");
   pubDate_flag = true;
    }

    if(link)
    {
       stringLink = new StringBuffer("");
       link_flag = true;
    }
}
```

}

**BINDADAPTER CLASS**

public class BindDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{

```
ArrayList<String> title;

ArrayList<String> cost;

ArrayList<String> pubDate;

LayoutInflater inflater;



//---------DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR-----------//

public BindDataAdapter()
{

}


//-------PARAMETERIZED CONSTRUCTOR------//

public BindDataAdapter(Activity activity , ArrayList<String> title , ArrayList<String> cost , ArrayList<String> pubDate)
{
    this.title = title;

    this.cost = cost;

    this.pubDate = pubDate;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return title.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent) 
{

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row , null);
    }

    TextView textViewtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);

    TextView textViewcost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cost);

    TextView textViewdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);


    //----I coudnot put text view using setText----//


    return convertView;
}
```

}

here is my MainActivity Class

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

```
static final String URLxml = "http://78.46.34.27/kapapps/transaction.xml";

String line = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


    try 
    {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader reader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

        URL sourceUrl = new URL(URLxml);

        ParseData data = new ParseData();

        reader.setContentHandler(data);

        reader.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

        BindDataAdapter bindDataAdapter = new BindDataAdapter(this , data.title , data.cost , data.pubDate);

        listView.setAdapter(bindDataAdapter);



    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SAXException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}
```

}

Comment: You don't need that flag system in your SAX parser, where did you learn to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ParseData` code should be just this:

```
public class ParseData extends DefaultHandler { 

    StringBuilder elementText;
    ArrayList<String> arrtitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrcost = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrpubDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrlink = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ParseData() {
        elementText = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri , String localName , String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ("title".equals(localName)) {
            arrtitle.add(elementText.toString().trim());
        } else if ("cost".equals(localName)) {
            arrcost.add(elementText.toString().trim());
        } else if ("pubDate".equals(localName)) {
            arrpubDate.add(elementText.toString().trim());
        } else if ("link".equals(localName)) {
            arrlink.add(elementText.toString().trim());
        }
        elementText.setLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        elementText.append(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, you should always make the HTTP request and XML parsing in a different thread (maybe using `AsyncTask`). Then, once response is parsed, update UI and show results. You need to make a lot of changes to make it run, bro.

In `getView` method, why can't you set strings to TextViews)? (just make use of `getItem(position)`)

**EDIT**

If your XML is like that, I would definetely define a JavaBeans class with all the subtags of  and then get a list of instances of that class as a result of the parser. It is the proper way to do this.

Type JavaBeans class to model each element of the XML:

```
public class Type {

    int id;
    String title;
    String cost;
    String date;
    String link;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
    public void setCost(String cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

And the parser now will construct a list of that class:

```
public class ParseData extends DefaultHandler { 

    StringBuilder elementText;
    List<Type> types;
    Type type;

    public ParseData() {
        types = new ArrayList<Type>();
        elementText = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ("type".equals(localName)) {
            type = new Type();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri , String localName , String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ("title".equals(localName)) {
            type.setTitle(elementText.toString().trim());
        } else if ("cost".equals(localName)) {
            type.setCost(elementText.toString().trim());
        } else if ("pubDate".equals(localName)) {
            type.setDate(elementText.toString().trim());
        } else if ("link".equals(localName)) {
            type.setLink(elementText.toString().trim());
        } else if ("type".equals(localName)) {
            types.add(type);
        }
        elementText.setLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        elementText.append(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Inside your `getView()` method you have to start an `AsycTask` that retrieves a `Bitmap` from a given `URL` (the one parsed from the XML). Inside the `doInBackground` method you can make use of `BitmapFactory` utility methods to retrieve the bitmap, and inside the `onPostExecute` method you can make use of `setImageBitmap` to set the retrieved bitmap to the `appropiate` ImageView.

Note: always prevent configuration changes problems, scrolling the list too fast or things like these by making use of `WeakReference` to the UI widgets or cancelling `AsyncTask` instances when appropiate.

Comment: thanks at least someone respond to my code, i thought no one would reply as am stuck, i am using your snippet let me see. here is my xml file:---- http://78.46.34.27/kapapps/transaction.xml

Comment: OK, and what is your problem? Can you parse it properly or not?

Comment: I have edited the response to propose a much better solution to your specific XML

Comment: i can parse it but i need to display it in a list view and by clicking on particular item on the list view it should display the image and some text in another activity.The problem is i can't get a string value of image view.Which is sad..i also tried converting into bitmap and passed in another activity but can't show because u need to parse the image to show uri.parse(imageurl);